# Container test with Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, json, selenium

How do I continue the selenium  test if an element does not exist, in c#?

```
if (type == "ID" && Event == "Click") {
     Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 
     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
     IWebElement element = 
     wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id(id)));
     element.Click();
}
else if (type == "ID") {
    webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(id)).SendKeys(key[data]);
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));
}
```

I want to skip the selenium element if it's not on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You may use exception handling to avoid test fail when there is no element

```
try
{
    webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
}
catch(NoSuchElementException)
{
}
```

Or use array, since finding multiple elements do not cause exception, just empty array.

```
IWebElement[] elements = webDriver.FindElements(By.Id(id)).ToArray();
if (elements.Count() != 0)
{
    do what you want
}
```

Comment: I want to skip a non existent item and don't stop the test selenium

Comment: Well... it does that.